# How to add time in strptime(), with date as well

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-parsing

I want to convert the date-time string into date-time object. I missing something can anybody tell me what it is I am missing?

```py
dummydate.append(datetime.strptime(row[0],"%m-%d-%Y:%H:%M:%SZ"))
```

I have this data in .csv format:

| date_time | maxtempC | mintempC | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2009 0:00 | 27 | 12 | ... |
| 1/1/2009 1:00 | 27 | 12 | ... |
| 1/1/2009 2:00 | 27 | 12 | ... |

[image: 1]

Comment: Format you passed to `strptime()` doesn't match with format you have in file. Take a look on [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Actually, everything is working, but when there is no time only the date is mentioned, but when I get the data where time is also present it gives me the output

ValueError: time data '2009-01-01 12:00:00' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y:%H:%M:%SZ'

Comment: To repeat Olvin's comment, parsing directive has to match the input! Where do you see a Z in "2009-01-01 12:00:00"?

Comment: Also, the format on the image you added is completely different- can you please clarify?